# Replace Zoom Image when click on More Views

Tags: magento-1.9, product, configurable-product, product-images, zoom

The Issue that i am facing is, when you click on more views, the main image gets replaced but the background zoom image remains the same as base image.

You can view the problem on [following link](https://golfoy.com/mizuno-t-zoid-spikes-men-s-golf-shoes-black.html), 
Select image from more views & try hover on the image.

Here is my code for the app.js file

```
swapImage: function(targetImage) {
    targetImage = $j(targetImage);
    targetImage.addClass('gallery-image');

    ProductMediaManager.destroyZoom();

    var imageGallery = $j('.product-image-gallery');

    if(targetImage[0].complete) { //image already loaded -- swap immediately

        imageGallery.find('.gallery-image').removeClass('visible');

        //move target image to correct place, in case it's necessary
        imageGallery.append(targetImage);

        //reveal new image
        targetImage.addClass('visible');

        //wire zoom on new image
        ProductMediaManager.createZoom(targetImage);

    } else { //need to wait for image to load

        //add spinner
        imageGallery.addClass('loading');

        //move target image to correct place, in case it's necessary
        imageGallery.append(targetImage);

        //wait until image is loaded
        imagesLoaded(targetImage, function() {
            //remove spinner
            imageGallery.removeClass('loading');

            //hide old image
            imageGallery.find('.gallery-image').removeClass('visible');

            //reveal new image
            targetImage.addClass('visible');

            //wire zoom on new image
            ProductMediaManager.createZoom(targetImage);
        });

    }
},

wireThumbnails: function() {
    //trigger image change event on thumbnail click
    $j('.product-image-thumbs .thumb-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var jlink = $j(this);
        var target = $j('#image-' + jlink.data('image-index'));

        ProductMediaManager.swapImage(target);
    });
},
```

Comment: If My answer help you then please accept My answer Or post your own answer which help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can add some custom jQuery for this as your zoom image is not changing
Write below code at the end of your js file.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.product-image-thumbs a.thumb-link img').click(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){ 
    jQuery('.zoomImg').attr('src',jQuery('.gallery-image.visible').attr('data-zoom-image'));
            }, 1000);

  });  });
```

Comment: This is sort of the solution i was looking for. But it is not working. I have even replaced jQuery with $j but the .zoomImg is not displaying the selected thumb image. How do i display the result of this function?

Comment: Ok i updated jQuery('.product-image-thumbs a.thumb-link img')

added li 

jQuery('.product-image-thumbs li a.thumb-link img')
Now, it is picking the previous image as zoomImg. Or you have to click on the thumb two times to have that replaced as Zoom imge

Comment: Its working now or what?

Comment: It is working after adding li , but it is picking the previous selected image or have to double click on the thumb to have it in effect.

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Perfect. This was a great help. Thank you